# Ways to make operator `<` work on custom types

Tags: operator-overloading, ocaml, adhoc-polymorphism

I have `type 'a edge = {from: 'a; destination: 'a; weight: int}`

and I want to have `Printf.printf "%b\n"
  ( {from= 0; destination= 8; weight= 7}
    < {from= 100; destination= 33; weight= -1} )` print true

so I tried this `let ( < ) {weight= wa} {weight= wb} = wa < wb`

but after this, the `<` operator only works on `'a edge`, and it means that `1 < 2` will raise an error.

---

the reason why I want to do this is below

I write a leftist tree

```
type 'a leftist = Leaf | Node of 'a leftist * 'a * 'a leftist * int

let rank t = match t with Leaf -> 0 | Node (_, _, _, r) -> r

let is_empty t = rank t = 0

let rec merge t1 t2 =
  match (t1, t2) with
  | Leaf, _ -> t2
  | _, Leaf -> t1
  | Node (t1l, v1, t1r, r1), Node (t2l, v2, t2r, r2) ->
    if v1 > v2 then merge t2 t1
    else
      let next = merge t1r t2 in
      let rt1l = rank t1l and rn = rank next in
      if rt1l < rn then Node (next, v1, t1l, rn + 1)
      else Node (t1l, v1, next, rt1l + 1)

let insert v t = merge t (Node (Leaf, v, Leaf, 1))

let peek t = match t with Leaf -> None | Node (_, v, _, _) -> Some v

let pop t = match t with Leaf -> Leaf | Node (l, _, r, _) -> merge l r
```

If I cannot make `<` work as I expect, I must pass in a compare lambda wherever the `<` is used and substitute it. And I find it unattractive.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml does not support adhoc polymorphism, but you can put the custom operator in a module that you can open locally only where you need it:

```
module Infix =
struct
  let ( > ) = ...
end

...

if Infix.(rt1l < rn) then ...
```

That way, `<` will work on `tree`s only inside `Infix.( ... )` and still refer to `Pervasives.(<)` outside it.

Comment: but in this way, the leftist tree can only be used on specific types still? so there's no way except passing in a compare lambda to make the leftist tree work on all types? Maybe I should make it a functor and use it like `Map.Make(String)`?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the question then. Yes, you need to give the tree a compare function for it to use. And you should also make a unique type to refer to a tree with this specific compare function. The easiest way to accomplish both is to use a functor, as you suggest.

Comment: OCaml might eventually gain adhoc polymorphism through and in-development feature called modular implicits, but it's been in development for a while so don't hold your breath just yet :)

Comment: You should define an `OrderedType` module as in for example  http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.OrderedType.html for your functor.